# How do I correctly use SelectSingleNode in Excel VBA to select a node in a large XML file

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have a spreadsheet of CVE numbers in Excel and I would like to import the Notes information from the Mitre CVE XML repository.  I’m pretty new to VBA and XPATH.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cvrfdoc xmlns="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1" xmlns:cvrf="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1 http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1/cvrf.xsd">
   <DocumentTitle xml:lang="en">CVE Output in CVRF 1.1: 20200109</DocumentTitle>
   <DocumentType>CVE List</DocumentType>
   <DocumentPublisher Type="Other">
      <ContactDetails>cve@mitre.org</ContactDetails>
      <IssuingAuthority>The MITRE Corporation</IssuingAuthority>
   </DocumentPublisher>
   <DocumentTracking>
      <Identification>
         <ID>20200109-041603</ID>
      </Identification>
      <Status>Interim</Status>
      <Version>2020.01.09.04</Version>
      <RevisionHistory>
         <Revision>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Date>2020-01-09T04:16:03</Date>
            <Description>Initial public release</Description>
         </Revision>
      </RevisionHistory>
      <InitialReleaseDate>2020-01-09T04:16:03</InitialReleaseDate>
      <InitialReleaseDate>2020-01-09T04:16:03</InitialReleaseDate>
      <Generator>
         <Engine>MITRE Custom CVE-to-CVRF Converter 2.0</Engine>
      </Generator>
   </DocumentTracking>
   <DocumentNotes>
      <Note Audience="All" Ordinal="1" Title="CVE List" Type="General">This is a list of CVE Identifiers as published by MITRE.</Note>
      <Note Audience="All" Ordinal="2" Title="License" Type="General">The MITRE Corporation (MITRE) hereby grants you a non-exclusive,  royalty-free license to use Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE (R)) for research, development, and commercial purposes. Any copy you make for such purposes is authorized provided that you reproduce MITREs copyright designation and this license in any such copy.</Note>
      <Note Audience="All" Ordinal="3" Title="Disclaimers" Type="General">ALL DOCUMENTS AND THE INFORMATION CONTAINED THEREIN ARE PROVIDED ON AN &amp;quot;AS IS&amp;quot; BASIS AND THE CONTRIBUTOR, THE ORGANIZATION HE/SHE REPRESENTS OR IS SPONSORED BY (IF ANY), THE MITRE CORPORATION, ITS BOARD OF TRUSTEES, OFFICERS, AGENTS, AND EMPLOYEES, DISCLAIM ALL WARRANTIES, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO ANY WARRANTY THAT THE USE OF THE INFORMATION THEREIN WILL NOT INFRINGE ANY RIGHTS OR ANY IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.</Note>
   </DocumentNotes>
   <Vulnerability Ordinal="135074" xmlns="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/vuln/1.1">
      <Title>CVE-2019-0001</Title>
      <Notes>
         <Note Ordinal="1" Type="Description">Receipt of a malformed packet on MX Series devices with dynamic vlan configuration can trigger an uncontrolled recursion loop in the Broadband Edge subscriber management daemon (bbe-smgd), and lead to high CPU usage and a crash of the bbe-smgd service. Repeated receipt of the same packet can result in an extended denial of service condition for the device. Affected releases are Juniper Networks Junos OS: 16.1 versions prior to 16.1R7-S1; 16.2 versions prior to 16.2R2-S7; 17.1 versions prior to 17.1R2-S10, 17.1R3; 17.2 versions prior to 17.2R3; 17.3 versions prior to 17.3R3-S1; 17.4 versions prior to 17.4R2; 18.1 versions prior to 18.1R3; 18.2 versions prior to 18.2R2.</Note>
         <Note Ordinal="2" Title="Published" Type="Other">2019-01-15</Note>
         <Note Ordinal="3" Title="Modified" Type="Other">2019-12-04</Note>
      </Notes>
      <CVE>CVE-2019-0001</CVE>
      <References>
         <Reference>
            <URL>http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/106541</URL>
            <Description>BID:106541</Description>
         </Reference>
         <Reference>
            <URL>https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10900</URL>
            <Description>CONFIRM:https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10900</Description>
         </Reference>
         <Reference>
            <URL>https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/package-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/RMKFSHPMOZL7MDWU5RYOTIBTRWSZ4Z6X/</URL>
            <Description>FEDORA:FEDORA-2019-5f14b810f8</Description>
         </Reference>
         <Reference>
            <URL>https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/package-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/W7CPKBW4QZ4VIY4UXIUVUSHRJ4R2FROE/</URL>
            <Description>FEDORA:FEDORA-2019-815807c020</Description>
         </Reference>
      </References>
   </Vulnerability>
```

The test bit of VBA I have is this:

```
Dim CVEnode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim XMLFile As Variant

Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

xDoc.resolveExternals = True
xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1'"

XMLFile = "Z:\CVE\allitems-cvrf-year-2019.xml"
If XMLFile = False Then Exit Sub
xDoc.Load (XMLFile)

Set CVEnode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:cvrfdoc/ns:Vulnerability/ns:Title[.='CVE-2019-0001']")
```

The XML file loads okay, and I can loop through the nodes and child nodes till I find the CVE I am looking for, but there are over 10k CVE entries for each year, so the looping option is quite slow.  I would like to jump right to the node I need but SelectSingleNode is not working for me.  When I run the code, I get a value of nothing for CVEnode.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: But how is the code *not* working? Are you getting an error? If yes, what is it?

Comment: You need to check the XML. When I test using what you posted the document does not load successfully - the object is "empty". When I deleted the "notes" stuff AND removed `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1 http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1/cvrf.xsd"` I could get the document to load correctly. Take a close look at what I deleted: there are two URIs but the last has no namespace in front of it.

Comment: And then you need to look at the namespace for the `Vulnerability` node: it's different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source XML has many namespaces. You need to specify them explicitly. To get to the **Vulnerability** fragment you need two of them.
Please try the following:

```
...
ns = "xmlns:cvrf='http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/cvrf/1.1' xmlns:ns2='http://www.icasi.org/CVRF/schema/vuln/1.1'"
xDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", ns
...
Set CVEnode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/cvrf:cvrfdoc/ns2:Vulnerability[ns2:Title='CVE-2019-0001']")
```

Comment: The two namespace prefixes did the trick.  I needed to remove the semicolons and the parentheses from your example above.  The node is now selected correctly.  This has set me well on the path to completely automating a very tedious chore.  Thank you and thanks to @Cindy for pointing out the different namespace for the vulnerability node.  I am new to all this and did not snap to that different namespace.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.